# Generating Attendance record of employees

Tags: php, mysql, report

Im trying to generate the summation of attendance of employee. The data is from the two table below.

```
Schedule /* This is the shift schedule of employee */

ID  Name     Schedule 
1   Paul     11:00PM - 8:00AM   
2   Juan     11:00PM - 8:00AM  
3   Elise    11:00PM - 8:00AM


Attendance  /* This is the logs of employee, it is name fp_logs */

ID  EmployeeID    Type       Datetime     
1        1         0          2015-07-25 22:00:00
2        2         0          2015-07-25 22:48:00
3        3         0          2015-07-25 20:48:00  
1        1         1          2015-07-25 08:00:00 
2        2         1          2015-07-25 08:44:00
3        3         1          2015-07-25 08:00:00
```

As you can see in attendance table, we have the column name "type" where in 0 is login and 1 is logout.

My script to generate report

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM employees";
$employees = $DB->getRecords($strSQL);

$from = strtotime("07/01/2015");  // Add post from date here
$to = strtotime("07/31/2015");    // Add post to date here


$total = array(
                array('fullname'=> '', 'days' => 0, 'inc' => 0, 'late' => 0, 'undertime' => 0, 'absent' => 0, 'nightdiff' => 0)
            );

    foreach($employees as $key => $emp){
        $empId = $emp['id'];
        $curDate = $from;
        while($curDate <= $to) {
            $sched = $DB->getRecord("select * from schedules where empid='$empId' and date(scheddate) = '".date('Y/m/d', $curDate)."'");

            $log = array(
                    'workingday' => @$sched['workingday'],
                    'day' => date('l', $curDate),
                    'login' => '',
                    'logout' => '',

                );

            $ltnow = date('Y/m/d', $curDate) < date('Y/m/d', NOW); //less than now

            if($ltnow) {
                    if(@$sched['workingday']) {

                        $log_range = array(
                            'shift_before' => "datetime between date_add('".date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($sched['datefrom']))."',interval -6 hour) and '".date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($sched['datefrom']))."'",
                            'shift' => "datetime between '".date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($sched['datefrom']))."' and '".date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($sched['dateto']))."'",
                            'shift_after' => "datetime between '".date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime($sched['dateto']))."' and date_add('".date('Y/m/d H:i:s',strtotime($sched['dateto']))."',interval +6 hour)"
                        );

                        $login = $DB->getRecord("select * from fp_logs where fp_id='$emp[fp_id]' and fp_id!='' and type='0' and $log_range[shift_before] limit 1");
                        $login_shift = $DB->getRecord("select * from fp_logs where fp_id='$emp[fp_id]' and fp_id!='' and type='0' and $log_range[shift] limit 1");
                        $logout_shift = $DB->getRecord("select * from fp_logs where fp_id='$emp[fp_id]' and fp_id!='' and type='1' and $log_range[shift] order by datetime desc limit 1");
                        $logout = $DB->getRecord("select * from fp_logs where fp_id='$emp[fp_id]' and fp_id!='' and type='1' and $log_range[shift_after] order by datetime desc limit 1");

                        $log['login'] = !empty($login['datetime'])?$login['datetime']:$login_shift['datetime'];
                        $log['logout'] = !empty($logout['datetime'])?$logout['datetime']:$logout_shift['datetime'];


                        $total[$key]['fullname'] = $emp['lname'] . ', ' .$emp['fname'];

                        if(empty($log['login']) && empty($log['logout'])) {

                            $total[$key]['absent']++;
                        } else {
                            if(empty($log['login']) || empty($log['logout'])) {

                                $total[$key]['absent']++;
                                $total[$key]['inc']++;
                            } else {
                                if((date('H:i:00', strtotime($sched['datefrom'])) == '07:00:00' && date('H:i:00', strtotime($sched['dateto'])) == '11:00:00') ||
                                    (date('H:i:00', strtotime($sched['datefrom'])) == '06:00:00' && date('H:i:00', strtotime($sched['dateto'])) == '10:00:00'))
                                    $total[$key]['days']+= .5;
                                else
                                    $total[$key]['days']++;

                                $total[$key]['late']        += getLate($sched['datefrom'], $log['login']);


                                $total[$key]['undertime']   += getUnderTime($sched['dateto'], $log['logout']);

                                $nd = getNightDiff($sched['datefrom'], $sched['dateto'], $log['login'], $log['logout']);
                                $nd = $nd<0?0:$nd;

                                $total[$key]['nightdiff'] += $nd;

                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        if(@$sched['schedtitle'] == 'Suspended') {
                            $total[$key]['absent']++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $curDate = strtotime(date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $curDate)." +1 day");

        }
    }
```

Currently it is working now, the problem is that, it takes 1 hour to generate 118 record of employees. If just 1 record it take 30 seconds. Is there anyway to make the script faster? I need to compute the total late, absent, undertime, incomplete, nightdiff of each employee. The attendance report generate like this.

```
Attendance Report

Name   Days     Late    Absent  Undertime   NightDiff   Incomplete
Paul    22       1         1       0            123         0
Juan    22       0         0       0            231         0  
Elise   22       0         0       0            223         0
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make this faster.

Comment: Your question was `Is there anyway to make the script faster?`, the answer is yes. Now, do you think we are here to read 200 rows of code, then do your job ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Posting my codes is simply showing that I did my job. What I'm asking is for other way to achieve my goal. If you cannot help it is ok. No one is forcing you to do so. Thank you

Comment: it should never work. you're storing `2015-08-25` in your dates, and comparing, as STRINGS, with `2015/08/25`. they will NEVER be equal...

Comment: @MarcB Opps sorry for that. It is only dummy data. Please ignore that.

Comment: you need to learn about sql [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s. probably most/all of your queries can be replaced with a SINGLE query using joins, which sould speed things up considerably. right now you're running 118*5+1 = 591 queries to generate all of this.

Comment: Can you please give me one example on how to apply sql JOIN on my query?